# XSD - Validate element which is a value of an attribute

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-validation

I have following xml.

```
<a>
  <thing tag="song1">
    <name>john doe</name>
    <email>john@example.com</email>
  </thing>
  <owner thing="/a/thing[@tag='song1']">
    ...
  </owner>
</a>
```

I want to assert in XSD that when 'thing' with tag 'song1' is present, 'owner' must have thing='/a/thing[@tag='song1'].

My logical try in XSD is

```
<sch:assert 
  test="(count(a:owner[@thing=a:thing[@tag='song1']]) > 0) = count(a:thing[@tag='song1']) > 0))">Error</sch:assert>
      </sch:rule>
```

Oxygen validator gives error for this xsd. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I ended up checking substring for song1 like this.

```
test="(count(a:thing[substring(@tag,19,8) = 'song1']) > 0)">
```

Its not perfect way as /a/thing and /./a/thing are equally right, but as far as I know users stick to the same pattern. Also in an ideal world, this case must be checked during run-time.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need a function which takes an XPath expression as a string and returns the result of evaluating it. That's available in Saxon as saxon:evaluate().

Secondly, assertions on a simple type only have access to the string being validated; assertions on a complex type have access to a tree rooted at the element node. Your path expression begins with "/" and therefore only works on a tree rooted at a document node. If you changed the path to `../a/thing[@tag='song1']` then you could validate it with an assertion on the a element of the form

```
assert test="every $o in owner satisfies exists(saxon:evaluate($o/@thing))"
```